# How do I make sure the print dialog settings are reset when Adobe Reader is closed?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, printing, adobe-acrobat, steadystate

we operate a printshop. several terminals (winvista+ms-steadystate). set up from 1 image.
lots of users and files daily. when a user leaves a terminal and quits adobe reader, strangley on some(!) terminals the next user inherits his print settings.

unfavourable - as some use 2x2 n-Up + duplex.

no "speedlauncher" running in the background. no process to keep a lock on values in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\AVGeneral
they read what the last user left in his print dialog

on staff pcs (winxp) with acrobat standard(8) the application defaults when it gets closed.

is this a reader problem, or windows print /or ms steadystate related?

default on application close -> wishful behaviour

Answer (score 0):

To me it's not clear if it only the Adobe Reader print settings that are remembered, or
all the system-wide defaults. If it is the former, and Adobe Reader stores it in the registry,
you could try write-protecting that registry key. Hopefully reader will silently ignore 
the resulting write error.